# Codeship marks the test as "failed" even when there is no error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, codeship

I have some rails-cucumber tests, all looks fine but CS says the test suite failed:
[image]

I didn't set "--strict" in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to investigate why it is that your process might be returning a non-zero exit code. The recommendation here is to hop into an [ssh debug](https://documentation.codeship.com/basic/builds-and-configuration/ssh-access/) for your build and verify that each step is returning a zero exit code:

`echo $?`